# Bugs started how do I fix? Error (Spring Boot + Thymeleaf)

Tags: spring

ERROR 8164 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

2021-01-24 16:55:32.459 ERROR 8164 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

2021-01-24 16:55:32.606 ERROR 8164 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Bugs started how do I fix?

Comment: Would be great to have more information. It looks like the connection to the Database fails.

Comment: What information do you need?